# changing background color of webbrowser control, using c# code, does not work on windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, webbrowser-control

Attached to the subject, the following c# code for changing background color of web browser's control works on Windows 7, but does not work on windows 10!

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
webBrowser1.Document.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot change the background color of a web browser in page load.. make event be called when document load is completed.

Comment: this piece of code written inside this event of document_Completed. Anyhow, this same code works for Windows 7, but not windows 10 ?!

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the browser control property color. If you want to change the inside browser control background color, you can do it by HTML. You can do it in the form load

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 webBrowser1.DocumentText ="<html><body style='background-color: blue;'></body></html>";
}
```

**Updated Answer:**
All the web pages are made by HTML. So that you can change the style using the HTML Element. Google has some sophisticated HTML. So I have made a trick and achieve the background color change.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com");
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  HtmlElement htmlElement = (from HtmlElement element in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div") select element)
               .Where(x=>x.Id != null && string.Compare(x.Id, "viewport", true)==0) .FirstOrDefault();
 if (htmlElement != null)
 {
  htmlElement.OuterHtml = htmlElement.OuterHtml.Replace("id=\"viewport\"", "id=\"viewport\" style=\"background-color:blue;\"");                
 }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this late code has covered the whole browser's content with Blue color. Where contents were not  visable!

Comment: What do you want exactly?. If you write anything inside the <body> tag it will be visible

Comment: hi, lets say i want to present the results of code:  webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com"); in the web browser :). So, i don't know how to convert results of this code to HTML's body as you suggest.

Comment: @KhaledH.Kukhon, I have updated the answer check now